# Gauss' Law and area vector

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, gauss-law

Recently I've been doing some physics exercises on electric and magnetic fields and read up somewhere that the vector area of a closed surface is equal to zero. That made me wonder why, when using Gauss' Law, the surface integral over dS (assuming E is constant, like when we use a sphere as the surface around the charge which is spread uniformly along a circle) is ever non-zero (as the law states that it considers net flux through a closed surface). Maybe I'm just mixing up some terms but I really need some clarification on this.

Comment: Because you use the surface vectors as a weight for other vectors (by taking the scalar product of the surface vectors with a vector field), so the integral cannot be reduced to something like "constant * integral over the surface vectors".

Comment: Vector area will ofcourse be zero.for a small area of the closed surface there will be vector in the outward direction.Now,for the whole surface there will be infinite  no of such vectors which cancel out and gives us a zero vector.
but In Gauss law you are taking surface integral of electric field which is a quite different case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauss' Law says $\iint_S \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{dA} = Q/\epsilon_0$ whereas the total vector area is $\iint_S \mathbf{dA}=\mathbf{0}$ for some closed surface $S$. The total vector area is taking vector sum of all the differential area vectors that are normal to the surface, whereas $\iint_S \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{dA} = Q/\epsilon_0$ is taking the *dot product* of the electric field and the differential area vector.

Let's use a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin as an example. Its clear that $\iint_S \mathbf{dA}=\mathbf{0}$ since, for every point on the sphere, the normal vector of that point cancels out with the point opposite it on the sphere. Therefore, $\iint_S \mathbf{dA}=\mathbf{0}$.

Now suppose there's a charge $Q$ at the origin. The electric field and the normal vector will be parallel at every point on the sphere, so the symmetry of the problem means $\iint_S \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{dA} = EA$ where $E$ and $A$ are the electric field and surface area of the sphere respectively.

Answer (score 1):

When you find the vector area of a closed surface you are dealing with vectors and the total sum is zero. However, when you use Gauss' law with a constant E what you are integrating is a scalar, and that gives you the surface (not zero).